# Insert GTiff-file into PostGIS table using raster2pgsql

Tags: python, postgis, psycopg2, postgis-raster

I am trying to insert a GTiff-file into a specific PostGIS table using the raster2pgsql-command. So far I managed inserting the GTiff-file into the PostGIS database I am connected to. But this creates a new table with the file-name of the GTiff-file. I could also move the raster-data to the target table afterwards, but I suppose there is a more efficient way.

Here is an example:

```
import psycopg2
import os

tif_path = 'test.tif'
conn = psycopg2.connect(
    host = 'localhost',
    port = 5432,
    user = 'postgres',
    dbname = 'gisdb'
    )
curs = conn.cursor()
curs.execute("SET postgis.gdal_enabled_drivers = 'ENABLE_ALL';")
os.system('raster2pgsql "%s" > temp.sql'%tif_path)
curs.execute(open('temp.sql','r').read())
```

Is there a way to insert the raster-data directly into an existing table?

I know I can use `-a` to append the raster to an existing table and specify the column name by using `-f`. But there doesn't seem to be a way to specify the name of the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to specify the table by yourself, your query must be like that:

```
raster2pgsql -s 4326 -I -C -M C:\temp\test_1.tif -t 100x100 myschema.mytable > out.sql
```

if you want to add the raster to existing table, you are right you must use "-a" value

Comment: Why hasn't anyone turned raster2pgsql.py into a python library with a simple API on top?